# How to remove a FIELD of "Text Object" in FastReport that has NULL Value

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, fastreport

Here my table:

[image: table]

QUESTION:

- How to remove the Field that has `NULL` Value?
- How is the appropriate Algorithm ?

Comment: It is not necessary to use "(in Delphi)" in your subject. The tags you've added tell us it's in Delphi, and the tags make sure that your question is shown to people watching the Delphi tag (or searching for Delphi questions or answers).

Answer (score 2):

You can suppress the printing of the label by setting its `Visible` property in the `OnBeforePrint` event in the report.

However, this will still leave you with a blank line, so you can solve this in one of three ways (in ascending order of difficulty).

1. Firstly, you can ignore suppression of the label printing detailed above and set the `Text` property of the field to be 'No' if the DB field is NULL in the `OnBeforePrint` or `OnGetText` events.
2. Alternatively, you can define a memo field and in the `OnBeforePrint` method calculate its `Text` property to only include the Non-Null values and their labels.
3. Finally, you can look at the documentation and use scripting to modify the Report Engine's `CurrX` and `CurrY` properties in order to suppress the blank lines.

Comment: Did you mean to say `OnGetValue` instead of `OnGetText`?

Comment: Hi @Andy_D thanks for your response, 1) i have tried your third slution by setting the CurrX and CurrY dynamically but All Fields in a line Shift while i want only (a) field(s) having null value shift(s), so i still have no i dea to handle this case.  2)i havealso tried your second solution, would you give the sample code to explain to me the point 2 ?  what do you mean in this statement "calculate its Text property" of course the Text Object has only 1 Text Property.   I did many searching in Google and i found a reference only such "FastReport Manual" that can help me, but still can't.

Comment: Do I need to use coding such ARRAY and LOOPing syntax ?

Comment: @user3193149 What I mean with my second solution is to replace all the conditional fields underneath the main order line with a single memo. You can then check that if the WithIce field is not null then add the text 'With Ice : Yes' to the memo then repeat the process for the other optional fields. Your memo will now only contain the non-null field and the report will look as you desire.